# Authentication/Authorization using Asp.net Core 2.1 and Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I'm trying to build up a test application to observe Identity Server 4.
Here is my use case:
1 - I have an application named AuthServer which would be responsible for Register/Login, Reset Password etc users
2 - I also have another WebApi application named **AppApi** which has all the protected endpoints.

Users should Register/login through the AuthServer app and user their token to access the protected endpoints in AppApi.

User credentials and profile info along with their roles should be saved in db just like when identity core is being used.

I know this is a very general question, But I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. All the resource I found were about authorizing clients (not users), or some scenarios that weren't helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Thank you, Adem, but this related to Identity core, not Identity Server. I'm particularly looking for a guide to set up A/A using identityserver.io

Comment: You can also try my tutorial: https://blog.georgekosmidis.net/2019/02/08/identityserver4-asp-dotnet-core-api-and-a-client-with-username-password/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with the IdentityServer4 samples [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples).  They show you how to authenticate users and APIs, which sounds like is both your questions.

Comment: Thank you the sample with Identity core is the one I was looking for.